# Unfortunately, <project name> has stopped

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I want Android get Wifi Router Name. MainActivity.java has this code. But When I run I get the following error Unfortunately,  has stopped. Thanks

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
String WifiName = wifiInfo.getSSID();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView outputWifiName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sysInf);

    outputWifiName.setText(WifiName);

}

private Activity getActivity() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Comment: can you post the log and the line of the stack?

Comment: getActivity is returning null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getActivity` returns null you should initialize `wifiMgr` inside `onCreate`

```
WifiManager wifiMgr =null;
WifiInfo wifiInfo = null;
String WifiName = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     wifiMgr= (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
    WifiName = wifiInfo.getSSID();
    TextView outputWifiName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sysInf);

    outputWifiName.setText(WifiName);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `getActivity' but at the same time override it to return`null`. 
This results in a`NullPointerException` in this line:

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line here

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

is going to be a problem since you are calling `getActivity()` before the `Activity` is created. Move that initialization and, consequently, the following initializations to `onCreate()`.

```
String WifiName;
WifiInfo wifiInfo;
WifiManager wifiMgr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Move those guys to here
    wifiMgr = (WifiManager)    
    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
    WifiName = wifiInfo.getSSID();

    TextView outputWifiName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sysInf);
    outputWifiName.setText(WifiName);
}
```